# How to use text function in R?

Tags: r

I am learning graphical analysis using R. Here is the code, which I can not understand.

```
barplotVS <- barplot(table(mtcarsData$vs), xlab="Type of engine")
text(barplotVS,table(mtcarsData$vs)/2,table(mtcarsData$vs),cex=1.25)
```

The output is like below. I can not understand the function of text(), I googled the text() function, which shows that the parameter of text(x,y) is numeric vectors of coordinates where the text labels should be written. Can anyone tell me what is `barplotVS,table(mtcarsData$vs)/2,table(mtcarsData$vs),cex=1.25` in my code.

[image]

Comment: It's just adding the labels inside the bars. If you are not familia with `R` you can look for a function's help by typing `?text` or `help("text")`. The first part is the boxplot object, the second the coordinates (x, y) the indicate where the text will be placed, the third part is actually the numbers (labels) and the last part is the size.

Comment: @patL I have looked the help. I just can not udnerstand why the parameter is a table.

Answer (score 1):

```r
barplotVS <- barplot(table(mtcarsData$vs), xlab="Type of engine")
print(barplotVS)
```

outputs:

```
     [,1]
[1,]  0.7
[2,]  1.9
```

These are the positions where the center of the bars in the barplot are on the `x` axis.

```r
print(table(mtcarsData$vs))
```

outputs:

```
 0  1 
18 14
```

the numbers below are the occurrences of each value that is present in `mtcarsData$vs` and the numbers above are the actual value that is counted.

When you run the function:

```r
text(barplotVS,table(mtcarsData$vs)/2,table(mtcarsData$vs),cex=1.25)
```

the first value will be the x positions where to put the labels (i.e. 0.7 and 1.9), the second parameter will be the y positions set in this case to total counts divided by two (i.e. 9 and 7) meaning to put the labels halfway in the bars, the third will be the labels (i.e. 18 and 14) and finally `cex` is a value that allows to change the size of the font.

Anyway R has in general a good documentation that you can call by using the `?` operator (as suggested in the comments). In order to understand try to run the code and check what each variable contains with `print` or `str` functions. If you use a IDE (e.g. RStudio) have the content of the variables in a graphical panel so you don't event need to print.

Comment: Can you tell me why the outputs of barplotVS is numeric values. Actually, it is a barplot instance.

Comment: @MRLi you need to check R documentation by calling `?barplot`. There is a section named __Value__ that explains what the function returns (in this case the mid points of the bars in the `x` direction). You shouldn't make assumptions only by reading the code because each library works in a particular way. For example base graphics (to which the `barplot` function belongs) usually don't return an object that represent the drawn graphics. Other packages like for example `ggplot2` do.

Comment: Yeah. I looked the barplot function in RDocumentation. I know the barplot object returns the midpoins of bar.